# Compare a pair of column from 2 sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to realize something like:

```
select column1 column2 from table1 
where column1 and column2 not in (select column1 column2 from table2)
```

and of course this is wrong, but how to build it correctly? Thanks a lot for your help!

Julie

Answer (score 2):

MySQL supports tuples for `in` and `not in`:

```
select column1 column2
from table1 
where (column1, column2) not in (select column1 column2 from table2);
```

That said, I prefer `jarlh`'s solution for two reasons (using `not exists`):

1. First, `not exists` treats `NULL` values more reasonably.
2. Not all databases support tuples for `in` and `not in`.  I use many different databases, so I prefer more common syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
select column1, column2
from table1 t1
where not exists (select *
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1.column1 = t2.column1
                    and t1.column2 = t2.column2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` as below

```
select t1.column1, t1.column2 
from table1 t1 
left join table1 t2 ON t2.column1 = t1.column1
    AND t2.column2 = t1.column2
WHERE t2.column1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 subqueries like this:

```
select column1, column2 from table1 
where column1 not in (select column1 from table2) 
and column2 not in (select column2 from table2)
```